# regex addition of character or number at the beginning and end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following conditions that I'm trying to meet with a regex (for a username validation):

- It must be between 6 and 30 characters long.
- It cannot have two consecutive periods, hyphens, underscores, or @ symbols.
- It must start and end with a letter or number.

I have the following which seems to work for the first two conditions. What would I add for the 3rd?

```
^(?=.{6,30}$)(?![.@-])(?!.*[_.@-]{2})^[a-zA-Z0-9._@-]{2,}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

**Examples of valid strings:**

```
test@test.com
1test-user
1test@test.com1
123456
asdfghjklpoiuytrewqasdfghjklpo
derghg$56
```

**Invalid:**

```
_testuser@test.com
testuser@test.com!
test..user
test_.
```

Comment: Can you please provide example strings? `(?=^.{6,30}$)(?=^[A-Za-z\d])(?=[A-Za-z\d]$)` could be a starting point that should cover `6 and 30 characters long`, `start and end with a letter or number`

Comment: just a regex isn't helpful since there's nothing to test it against. Please share that so there is a complete demo here.

Comment: Any reason for insisting on using regex? A plain sight clear function `testUsername` with the logic splitted into several statements, clean and readable would be far better. Not only for debugging or later improvements, expansions...

Comment: "two consecutive periods, hyphens,underscores, or @ symbols" Does this mean it can have `.@` but not `..`? Or it can't have any consecutive punctuations?

Comment: Why you allow `_` at the start? For the rest, it seems you implemented the rules. What is the problem? Any strings you can provide that give the wrong result?

Comment: @Barmar - it can't have two consecutive of any of those - so test@-user would be invalid - sorry to everyone if my question wasn't clear

Comment: The question is really unclear. I would not only edit it to improve it, but also showcase some test usernames, good ones and bad ones.

Comment: Can it have other puncutation besides the 4 you mention?

Comment: that means that `@1@2@3@4etc` is a valid username (since `@` are not consecutive). Your edit is just not enough.

Comment: This can not be valid as there are 5 characters `12345` I think your pattern can be simplified using a case insensitive match to `^(?=.{6,30}$)[a-z\d]+(?:[@._-][a-z\d]+)*$` if `123456` should be a match. See https://regex101.com/r/t0MBVx/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird you are correct, i updated the 12345 as that would be invalid - thanks!

Comment: @Thefourthbird - one example that's not valid but should be from your regex is derghg$56  - the name can have characters in it, just not two periods (.), hyphens (-),underscores (_), or at symbols (@) in a row.

Comment: @user1822065 I see, but note that your own pattern also does not match `$` as you only allow these characters `[a-zA-Z0-9._@-]` In that case you can negate it `^(?=.{6,30}$)[a-z\d][^\s@._=]+(?:[@._=][^\s@._=]+)*[a-z\d]$` https://regex101.com/r/crHYbj/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird - sorry it's still letting test--test through as valid - it can't have two of those in a row?

Comment: @user1822065 Which values does it let through? What do you mean by `it can't have two of those in a row?` ?

Comment: @Thefourthbird test--user is allowed and should not be (no 2 hyphens in a row) also for example, a_12345 or 1@12345 should be allowed as they are at least 6 characters and start and end with a number or digit.

Comment: @user1822065 See https://regex101.com/r/kKgyNt/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird - thanks if you check this,i think you might see the ones that are incorrect - thanks a ton for your help!

https://regex101.com/r/mKeWZE/1

Answer (score 0):

You can make a negative match, looking for invalid patterns. That makes it easy just combine with `|` anything you want.

The only problem I don't understand

> It cannot have two consecutive periods, hyphens,underscores, or @ symbols.

whether it's about the same symbol or any from the list.

Anyway I hope you got the idea:

```js
/*
It must be between 6 and 30 characters long.
It cannot have two consecutive periods, hyphens,underscores, or @ symbols.
It must start and end with a letter or number.
*/
const valid = `
test@test.com
1test-user
1test@test.com1
12345
asdfghjklpoiuytrewqasdfghjklpo
`;

const invalid = `
user%name
_testuser@test.com
testuser@test.com!
test..user
test_.
`;

// 12345 - seems invalid since less than 6 chars

const names = ['ok_user@name', '2@.user', 'asdf', 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasd', '_asdfs', '2asdf__']
names.unshift(...valid.match(/\S+/g));
names.unshift(...invalid.match(/\S+/g));

names.forEach(str => 
  console.log(str, 'is valid:', !/^.{0,5}$|^.{31,}$|[-_.@]{2}|^[^a-z0-9]|[^[^a-z0-9]$|[^-\w_.@]/.test(str))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Studying your regex, you seem to have a 4th condition: only allowed characters are alphanumerics,hyphens,underscores, or @ symbols.
2. So, why don't you combine what is at the start with what is at the end? First do your duplicate lookahead check `(?!.*[_.@-]{2})` and then recognize that a string of 6-30 with alphanumerics at each end is the same as a 4-28 string sandwiched between alphanumerics `[A-Z0-9][\w.@-]{4,28}[A-Z0-9]`.  Put them together with:

`^(?!.*[_.@-]{2})[A-Z0-9][\w.@-]{4,28}[A-Z0-9]$`

If you assert the case insensitive flag (i), doesn't that take care of it?

**EDIT**

If all characters are allowed in the string's interior (as explained in the below comment), then just replace the `[\w.@-]` with a simple `.`.  You get this:

```
^(?!.*[_.@-]{2})[A-Z0-9].{4,28}[A-Z0-9]$
```

Comment: thanks for your response - actually the condition only specifies that it cannot have two consecutive periods (.), hyphens (-),underscores (_), or at symbols (@) - so from the instruction, something like tester$r would be valid - how does that change  what you have here?

Comment: @ChrisMaurer Very nice one! Only one lookahead :) A tiny idea maybe to shift the lookahead after the `^[A-Z0-9]` part but that's "complain" on high level.

Comment: @bobble bubble, yes saving that microsecond by skipping the first character is critical ;)

Comment: @ChrisMaurer - thanks again but this still doesn't seem to do the trick - here is what i have and it seems close but still not working 100% https://regex101.com/r/ueHoPt/2

Comment: @user1822065 - The regex above after **EDIT** accepts ALL your valid cases in Regex101 and rejects ALL of your invalid cases.  Did you forget to turn on the "i" flag to make your matches case insensitive?